# Paste From QT Window to Another Application Input Widget

Tags: c++, winapi

I am very new to C++ programming and the bulk of my program will be using the QT libraries. However, there is one part where I believe I will need to use Win32.

The scenario I want to code for is as follows:

I will have a QT application running. I want to be able to take some text which has been typed into a TextBox on the QT Window and paste that text into a TextBox in another application e.g. the address bar of Chrome, the address bar of Windows Explorer.

I want to be able to do that as a response to a button click on the QT Window. So, it would all happen in 3 steps. For example:

1. User types text into QT Window;
2. User places cursor in address bar of Chrome (Browser);
3. User clicks button on Window which pastes text into address bar of Chrome.

A nudge in the right direction would be most appreciated.

**Edit - Additional Info**

The application I’m building is a self-set assignment. I want to build a clipboard manager, similar to this old Delphi application http://www.joejoesoft.com/vcms/97/ . It will run in the system tray, in a minimised state.

1. The user, will put their focus into a text input in some application
   which is running on their Windows machine e.g. Notepad.
2. Then, they will hit a hot key combination which will open a form (my QT Window.
3. The application will have been collecting clips as the user presses Ctrl-C (or by right-clicking) and those will be listed in that QT Form (just like the app in the link above).
4. The user then clicks on the particular item that they want paste and it will be pasted into the original input that they had put the cursor into.

**Further Edit - further info**

I'll break step 4 into a couple of sub-steps as it is causing confusion:

1. The user then clicks on the particular item that they want paste
2. Focus changes from QT Window back to the window of the other Win32 application which originally had focus
3. Content is pasted into the input control which now has the focus

I pretty much know how I can gather up items when the user copies things. But I have no idea how I will paste from my application to the target application.

Cheers

Comment: Look around MIME data, I'm pretty sure there's a qt thing for that :). I can't check right now but I might have some code if you can't find anything.

Comment: @TheRealNox would that also be the case for another Windows application? I used Chrome and Windows Explorer (not IE), but my use case could be pasting into any possible application which has a textbox e.g. Google Earth search TextBox. Or a TextBox in Filezilla (off the top of my head).

Comment: So here you are QClipboard http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html

Comment: @TheRealNox: Please, do not abuse the clipboard for this. The clipboard belongs to the user, not your application.

Comment: @IInspectable I was planning on using the clipboard. And I want to paste the contents of it into another non-QT application. That is, Chrome, Notepad, Filezilla - anything that accepts text. So, my stated spec is incorrect. My over-arching idea is to paste from my QT app to anything that accepts text.

Comment: Can you explain what your Qt program looks like and how it should work?

Comment: @andlabs I have amended my question to add more details about the application. I was initially brief in my description as I was trying to describe a proof of concept for just the pasting part. Hopefully, the complete picture will make it easier to advise. Thanks.

Comment: You already have an answer. See QClipboard. It does what you need. @RealNox said it.

Comment: @purplehuman Are you sure? I cannot see anywhere in that API which would help in pasting OUTSIDE of the QT application.

Comment: You can't paste in another application. All applications have their own pasting code. You can only see what's in the clipboard, and handle them, for example with setImage() or setText() function. The other application pastes itself. But maybe you can call the system's paste command somehow, that I don't know.

Comment: @purplehuman There's a link in my post to a Delphi application called ArsClip which does exactly what I am trying to do. Basically, I'm trying to write that application again. I use it every day and it does paste into the other application.

Comment: @DavidRogersDev So, there should be a way to call the system's paste command somehow. Like I said, I don't know that. But QClipboard has all Qt have for clipboards. You can invoke CTRL+V shortcut maybe somehow.

Comment: Of course you can send a [`WM_PASTE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649028.aspx) message to your target window. I would still argue, that messing with the clipboard will be perceived as rude. Your application should not destroy a user's data.

Comment: @IInspectable Cool. Nearly there. Do you know how I could get a hook on the target window? I just need a nudge in that direction. Getting a reference to that target window, which I assume is a Win32 thing.

Comment: I think the article at this link contains enough for me to move on - [Add-Your-Control-On-Top-Another-Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80255/Add-Your-Control-On-Top-Another-Application)

Thanks to all for throwing ideas into the pot.